# Is there a JavaScript spy/mock/stub library that doesn't use eval?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, bdd, firefox-os

I have an HTML5 app that targets Firefox OS, among others. Packaged apps in Firefox OS can't use eval. (A CSP of

```
default-src *; script-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

is in force and can't be relaxed.)  My app does not itself use eval, but the spy/mock/stub libraries I know of, such as Sinon, do.  So my unit tests that use a spy, mock or stub fail when running under Firefox OS. (They succeed in a regular browser.)  Obviously, I could manually create spies, mocks and stubs, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Is there a JavaScript spy/mock/stub library that doesn't use eval?

Comment: https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/710

Comment: You could check out [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/). A quick look through their source code didn't turn up in references to `eval` in their `SpyStrategy` and `SpyRegistry` classes, which is used to implement mocks and spies in Jasmine.

Comment: You are running your unit tests within a packaged Firefox OS app on Firefox OS? That is impressive :) For test running purposes, could you maybe just run them in Firefox and still receive adequate coverage? The main difference would be missing APIs which you'd have to mock out. You probably don't need to test those APIs directly though.

Comment: Unit tests can be run in a browser, but not all functional tests can be. In particular, support for HTML5 APIs is changing rapidly, and it's important to know if, for example, writing to a file *actually* succeeds on any given platform.  Jasmine 2.x has decent support for async tests, so I will give it another chance.

Answer (score 0):

The spies of Jasmine 2.2 (http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Spies) indeed run fine in a Firefox OS app, and you can use the more natural Mocha syntax for asynchonous tests.

It did take an irksome amount of time to rewrite my tests, though, since Jasmine expects and spies have a different syntax than expect.js and sinon.js.